# Angularjs filter on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button where I am passing the value back to the controller:

```
<button type="button" ng-model="activeCustomer" value="active" ng-click="getVal($event)" ng-class="{'active':activeCustomer === 'active'}" class="btn btn-default">Active</button>
```

Its being stored in the controller like this:

```
$scope.activeCustomer='active';
$scope.getVal=function(active){
        $scope.activeCustomer=active.currentTarget.value;
    }
```

I want to filter my list by  `$scope.activeCustomer` if `detail.activeCustomer` = `$scope.activeCustomer`

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in theRecords | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchCustomer" ng-click="expandCustomer(detail.theCustId)" class="drillable">
    <td>{{ detail.fullname }}</td>
    <td>{{ detail.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ detail.phone }}</td>
    <td>
      <p ng-bind="{{ detail.firstcontact }} | date:'dd/MM/yy'"></p>
    </td>
    <td>{{ detail.theMainAddress }}</td>
    <td>{{ detail.paymentType  }}</td>
    <td>{{ detail.theStatus }}</td>
    <td>{{ detail.activeCustomer }}</td>
  </tr>
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you used $filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close with what you have.

You're already setting the activeCustomer in your controller. Just pass that to the filter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in theRecords | 
    orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:activeCustomer">
```

Comment: wow I cant believe that works I've been struggling with this for ages! Thanks!! It looks like it doesn't match the exact value though... when i search "inactive" it only shows inactive records but searching "active" returns both active and incative. Do you know any way to resolve this? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure! There's a second parameter you can pass to the filter to determine how the comparison happens. Just passing 'true' should work. `filter: activeCustomer : true`